# JScrollPane scrollbar disappears on window resizing

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jeditorpane

This is an attempt to get two JEditorPane components sharing a common scrollbar and displaying the same content fetched over a URL. But, I am facing these challenges:

1. JEditorPane **translation** (right one) is not getting the HTML content **helpURL** (common expected).
  **Edit:**
  Any of the two and one at a time is showing the content right, plus there is no exception thrown.
2. The scroller (to outermost JScrollPane **panelScrollPane**) disappears on window resizing.

Fot tl;dr: **Find scrollbar policy in myInitComponents method and content setting in fetchURL method.**

```
package test;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

public class URLReader extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    /**
     * Creates new form URLReader
     */
    public URLReader() {
        initComponents();
        myInitComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        panelScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        contentPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        leftScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        content = new javax.swing.JEditorPane();
        rightScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        translation = new javax.swing.JEditorPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Content Panel", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12))); // NOI18N

        leftScrollPane.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Content"));

        content.setContentType("text/html"); // NOI18N
        content.setAutoscrolls(false);
        leftScrollPane.setViewportView(content);

        rightScrollPane.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Translation"));
        rightScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        translation.setContentType("text/html"); // NOI18N
        rightScrollPane.setViewportView(translation);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout contentPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(contentPanel);
        contentPanel.setLayout(contentPanelLayout);
        contentPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            contentPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(contentPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(leftScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 345, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(rightScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 296, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        contentPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            contentPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(contentPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(contentPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(leftScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 336, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(rightScrollPane))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        panelScrollPane.setViewportView(contentPanel);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(panelScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 710, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(panelScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 372, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(12, 12, 12))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    private void myInitComponents(){
        leftScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        leftScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        rightScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        rightScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        panelScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        panelScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        /*
        content.setLineWrap(true);
        content.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        translation.setLineWrap(true); 
        translation.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        */
    }

    private void fetchURL(String url){
        try{
            // URL(URL baseURL[, String relativeURL])
            URL helpURL = new URL(url);
            this.content.setPage(helpURL);
            this.translation.setPage(helpURL);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Attempted to read a bad URL: " + url);
        }
        // return this.content;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(URLReader.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(URLReader.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(URLReader.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(URLReader.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String url = "http://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A0";
                URLReader reader = new URLReader();
                reader.fetchURL(url);
                reader.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JEditorPane content;
    private javax.swing.JPanel contentPanel;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane leftScrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane panelScrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane rightScrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JEditorPane translation;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

P.S.: I am passing full code (NetBeans IDE) for better perspective, if not suitable, please direct so, I will try to shorten this. Thanks.

Comment: Using Netbeans Matisse generates code that is not correctly resizeable

Comment: Any changes I could make herein to test as I am not yet fully comfortable with making them on my own, still learning! Or any better suggestions, please!